# How to set minDate in datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Below is the check_in and check_out

```
<input type="text" id="check_in" name="check_in" value="Thursday, 17 Apr, 2014">
<input type="text" id="check_out" name="check_out" value="Friday, 18 Apr, 2014">
```

This is the date picker i used

```
$('#check_in').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '1Y',
    defaultDate:'+1d',
    numberOfMonths:2,
    dateFormat:'DD, d M, yy',
    onSelect: function(date){         
        var startDate = $('#check_in').datepicker('getDate');
        var date = new Date( Date.parse( startDate ) );
        date.setDate( date.getDate() + 1 );
        var newDate = date.toDateString();
        newDate = new Date( Date.parse( newDate ) );
        $('#check_out').datepicker('option','minDate',newDate);
        startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 30);
        $('#check_out').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', startDate);
    }
});

$('#check_out').datepicker({
    minDate: '1D',
    maxDate: '30D',
    defaultDate:'+1d',
    numberOfMonths:2,
    dateFormat:'DD, d M, yy'            
});
```

Here in the page load when i click check_out datepicker, 'minDate' not starting from 18 april. one's i select 17 april from check_in datepicker its working fine

How i set that minDate based on check_in date when i go direct to check_out datepicker?

Comment: Which date you want to set?

Comment: i need to set check_out date start from Friday, 18 Apr, 2014 in datepicker

Comment: You can use `minDate: new Date(2014, 4 - 1, 18),`

Comment: i try like this minDate:new Date($('#check_in').val()).getDate()+1 but its showing 25 april why? http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/Z74Q2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var oneD=24*60*60*1000;
t1=new Date($('#check_in').val()).getTime();
t2=new Date().getTime();
var diffDays = Math.round((t1 - t2)/(oneD))+2;
$('#check_out').datepicker({
    minDate: diffDays+'D',
    maxDate: '30D',
    defaultDate:'+1d',
    numberOfMonths:2,
    dateFormat:'DD, d M, yy'            
});
```

**[Live Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/Z74Q2/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, its not starting 18 april. its starting from Friday, 25 Apr, 2014